# how to store key-value pair data in program without using any DBMS?

Tags: android, c++, qt

i want to build a dictionary in C++ and qt and later for android,which will have a word and meaning.the easy option is to use sqlite or mysql like DBMS but i dont want to use them as sqlite is not secure(anyone can open that sqlite database to copy my word-meaning pair) and mysql needs a large installer file  to be deployed along with installer.is there any way in which i can store my word-meaning pair in program?or can i store that word-meaning pain in a string array?there are 120000 words and almost 360000 meaning so if i make a string string word_meaning[360000][2]? will it be a problem to load the program?

or using a password protected zip?is it a viable solution?

kindly recommend any other secure and better method

regards

Comment: Your definition of secure is flawed. You seem to ask for DRM. Hollywood couldn't buy that for a few billion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like MSalters says, there is no way to make it guaranteed unbreakable, but you can make it pretty hard. And if you make it hard enough to break your security so that it is not worth the effort then you are secure enough.

You have a trade off between programming complexity and security.

The most secure that I can think of is putting the database on your own server and have your app query the server. That way no hacker has access to your database. But perhaps you also have a need for high performance when looking through the dictionary or you don't want your game to need internet.

The next thing I can think of is to place an encrypted text file with the word-meanings in your app's assets directory. Your app will contain the key to decrypt the text file and a hacker would need to decompile your app and find the key before he can decrypt the file to steal your dictionary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the help was very helpful,thanx for that.i want to design the same application for PC using QT for linux and windows
what strategy i shud use there?

Comment: On PC it would work the same as on Android. Either query your dictionary on a server, or make it an encrypted, embedded resource text file.